# How to run docx in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, docx

I have installed docx, but it does not work in Spyder. Docx works in other shells, but I receive this error when I attempt to use it in Spyder.

```
from docx import Document

File "C:\Users\Jacob\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx.py", line 30, in     <module>
from exceptions import PendingDeprecationWarning

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'exceptions'
```

I looked though my Anaconda files for docx and it was there.

Comment: figured it out very shortly after posting this. use pip install python-docx instead of pip install docx